# How do I prevent the submit changelist dialog from resizing and maximizing the submit dialog window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-integrate

I need to disable the maximize and resize feature in our submit changelist dialog box.

I am having a html file that is having the contents as same as default submit changelist. But with some extra fields and styles using jquery.

But if I am trying to resize the dialog box. All the html content have been collapsed. It is not getting adjust with our dialog box height and width.

Is their anyway to disable the resizing and maximizing property of our submit changelist dialog?

Comment: Are you talking about the regular submit dialog in P4V?  Or did you implement a submit dialog in Javascript?

Comment: No Regular submit dialog only.